# How to change Vim from "-xterm_clipboard" to "+xterm_clipboard" in Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: vim, osx-mavericks

I am new to vim, and I am trying to paste content from other applications. I am running the native vim that comes with the OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

When I run "vim --version" this is the output

```
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
-conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs 
-dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path 
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv 
+insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent 
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape 
-mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse 
+mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype 
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python/dyn 
-python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind +signs 
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
```

I understand I need to change "-xterm_clipboard" to "+xterm_clipboard" to be able to paste the content form other sources.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install your own Vim. If you haven't already, setup [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), then:

```
brew install macvim --override-system-vim
```

Bonus is that MacVim can run as a native application, i.e. outside the terminal, like gVim on other platforms. It is also compiled with the "huge" featureset, so you have pretty much everything in it that you'd need, unlike the system Vim.

EDIT: Apparently the option name changed; the new syntax should be

```
brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim
```

(See `brew options macvim` for more options.)

Comment: I already had macvim installed, but I thought there was another way to have Vim installed with "+xterm_clipboard". Finally I decided start using macvim but without overriding vim. Thank you @Amadan.

Comment: Why would you not override Vim with MacVim? In terminal, MacVim (softlinked to vim, in this configuration) behaves, for all intents and purposes, identically to Vim. I.e. you get all the benefits of the "huge" featureset like Ruby/Python integration etc, with no downsides.

Comment: you were right, there was no reason for not overriding the vim that came by default. Thank you

Comment: This is not a satisfactory answer.  

There ARE reasons for using VIM instead of MVIM, such as remote pairing with TMate, or running tests in a split with TMux.

Comment: @FreePender: I'm not following - please explain why you can't do that with terminal MacVim.

Comment: For example, you can wrap Terminal VIM in a TMux session, which allows you to use TMate.  Then you can SSH into another person's Vim to pair program.

MacVim is great, and often does solve a lot of issues, but it runs as a GUI process outside of the terminal, so it won't allow this.

You can also run: `brew install vim --override-system-vim`, which will override the system vim, and should ship with `xterm-clipboard` support.

Comment: @FreePender: No, just no. MacVim runs in a terminal just fine. It runs in tmux just fine, too. When overriding system Vim, `mvim` and `vim` run the same executable, just like `vimdiff`, `mvimdiff`, `view` and `ex` (and I've probably forgotten a couple others). Depending on the filename by which it is invoked, it modifies its behaviour: when overriding system Vim, the command `vim` runs MacVim (not Vim!) in a terminal and, as I said above already, behaves for all intents and purposes just like Vim; and when run as `mvim`, runs in GUI and provides extra value to Mac users.

Comment: Small note, just ran this and saw: `Warning: macvim: --override-system-vim was deprecated; using --with-override-system-vim instead!`

Comment: FYI, in newer versions of brew this should be `brew reinstall macvim -- --with-override-system-vim`. See https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/issues/817#issuecomment-496861257
(I'm on 2.1.7, I'm not sure when this started)